# Variable persistence inside SQL server transactions

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've got a large T-SQL script that opens and closes a few transactions. I have read that committing a batch with a GO statement effectively clears all variables out from it's scope.

Given the script below, will @MyImportantVariable be defined after the transaction is committed?

Is this an issue, if so, how do I overcome it?

```
DECLARE @MyImportantVariable INT;
SET @MyImportantVariable = 42;

DECLARE @Counter INT;
SET @Counter = 0

DECLARE UpdateGarmentCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR
SELECT
        MyColumn
    FROM
        MyWonderfulTable

BEGIN TRANSACTION
    WHILE @@TRAN_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN
        -- Do interesting work in here
    SET @Counter = @Counter +1
    IF(@Counter>10) 
    BEGIN
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
            -- What happens here to @MyImportantVariable?
           SET @Counter = 0
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
    END
END

-- Close the transaction one last time
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable will still exist.

Your example contains no `GO` commands, only transactions.

`GO` signals the end of a *batch*... batches and transactions are two different things entirely.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx):

> GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the
>   sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code
>   editor.
>
> SQL Server utilities interpret GO as a signal that they should send
>   the current batch of Transact-SQL statements to an instance of SQL
>   Server. The current batch of statements is composed of all statements
>   entered since the last GO, or since the start of the ad hoc session or
>   script if this is the first GO.